# c++ typedef/type substitution for enumeration class

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, typedef, enum-class

As far as I am aware at the moment it is not possible to do a `typedef` of the C++11 `enum class`. I would like to know if there is any other way I can reduce the length of the name of a variable `enum` when referring to it outside of the encapsulating class. Here is an example:

```
// I would like to do something along the lines of:
class SegmentActivityState;
using SegmentActivityType = SegmentActivityState::ActivityStateType;

// ...However, this results in the compile time error:
// 'SegmentActivityState' does not name a type. 

// Enumeration class definition
class SegmentActivityState
{
public:
    enum class ActivityStateType : Index
    {
        PreExecution = 0,   /**< Pre-execution state. */
        Execution = 1, /**< Execution state. */
        PostExecution = 2 /**< Post-execution state. */
    };

private:
    ActivityStateType ActivityState;
    /**< unique object identifier tag. */

public:
    // ... Methods that work on the ActivityState
}
```

The most important issue is the length of the name by which I have to refer to the `enum` outside of `SegmentActivityType`. For example, in order to do a type comparison I need to write `SegmentActivity.getState() == SegmentActivityState::ActivityStateType::PreExecution`, which is very verbose. Two things that I would prefer not to do are:

1. `typedef` on `SegmentActivityState`.
2. Move the `enum class`ActivityStateType`outside of the class`SegmentActivityState` definition.

Comment: When you attempt to create the type alias, the symbol `SegmentActivityState::ActivityStateType` doesn't exist yet. You can simply move it to after the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with it being an enum. You can't do it because you're trying to access a member of an undefined class. This will never work no matter what the member is.

Put the typedef after the class definition and this [will be completely fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce8120f8e08578ba).